# How to send an arrow key in a WatiN test?

Tags: automated-tests, watin

I have a WatiN test where I want to trigger a datepicker by sending a down arrow in a text field.  I can't seem to find anywhere how to send a down arrow in a WatiN test.  Do I need to run a piece of javascript via the Document.Runscript?

Thanks,
Matthew

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using the [SendKeys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.aspx) class:

```
System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys("{DOWN}");
```

If you want to use javascript maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596481/simulate-javascript-key-events/596580#596580) can help.